# Connect to Tuxedo from tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, bea, tuxedo

What's the best method/technology to connect to a Oracle Tuxedo 11gr1 from a Tomcat7 server, using Java of course? I've been researching the topic, I came down to two solutions, but they just don't work for me:

- You can use Oracle Tuxedo JCA adapter (not supported on tomcat7, and require advanced AP implementation for J2C compliance)
- You can use Jolt API, but still that will require to enable the Jolt API on the Tuxedo server which i don't have access to

Answer (score 1):

You could connect from Tomcat to Tuxedo using:

- Jolt (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18050_01/tuxedo/docs11gr1/install/insjol.html)
- SALT (enables connection via webservices) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35855_01/salt/docs12c/overview/index.html
- Oracle Service Bus

All of them require a modification in Tuxedo domain.